# Arduino EthernetServer is possible initialize in setup?

Tags: arduino

I wonder if it is possible to initialize the EthernetServer Arduino inside the setup function.

The idea is before you start reading the eeprom Arduino and choose the port recorded in eeprom to boot EthernetServer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restrictions on what code you can run in setup() or how long it takes to run.

What you want to do with it sounds ideal.

I would suggest that for readability and future code recycling that you put the required initialization into a separate function that you call from setup()

Answer (score 0):

Initially, It may not be as simple as it sounds like. Since the listening port appears to be defined with the constructor of the server instance.

```
EthernetServer server(80); // listening on port 80.
```

which you have noted is typically instantiated globally. Where the

```
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
server.begin();
```

are exampled in the setup. Where moving the instantiation within the setup() will make it local and only exist within the setup() and NOT exist in the loop().

Additionally it appears from the library the server listening port is a private attribute, not publicly changeable, nor is there any method to change it. Other than it being set during the constructor.

Two possible work-a-rounds:

1) could change the library. Either add a method to change it, before the begin. Or add it to the begin.

better than changing a stock library.
2) Would be to move the instantiation and the begin to be within the loop() encapsulated by a oneshot, as to occur only once.

below is the modification of the stock WebServer.ino example. Which appears to both compile and work for me.

```
...
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

bool once;
int listenPort;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
  once = 1;
  listenPort = 81;
}

void loop() {
    EthernetServer server(listenPort); // been moved from global. I believe this becomes global to the reiterations of loop().

  if (once) { // do just once.
    once = 0;
    // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
    // all been moved from global.
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    server.begin();
    Serial.print("server is at ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }

  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

but this way will get this command is always executed in the loop infinitely

EthernetServer server (listenport);

this consumes processing

not consume?

void loop() {
    EthernetServer server(listenPort); // been moved from global. I believe this becomes global to the reiterations of loop().

Dario

Answer (score 0):

Could you construct `server` as a static variable within `setup` and have a pointer declared as a global variable. Then simply update the pointer to point to `server` after `server` has been constructed.

```
...

EthernetServer* serverPt;

void setup()
{
  ...
  int portNum;
  ...
  static EthernetServer server(portNum);
  serverPt = &server;
  server.begin();

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using a pointer, then you must use "->"

Example:
server->begin();